# Camera Preview does not fill screen

Tags: ios, ipad, avfoundation, ios6

This is how I am setting up the camera preview in landscape mode in my iPad3

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

{

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;

CALayer *viewLayer = self.vImagePreview.layer;

NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.bounds;
[self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}
[session addInput:input];

stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

[session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

[session startRunning];
```

}

In the storyboard, I set the view to fill the entire screen, however it ends up looking like this:

[image]

And furthermore, the image is also rotated 90º degrees. How can I change this, so I can make the camera preview fill the entire screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotate your layer:

```
    switch (self.interfaceOrientation)
    {
     case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
       [captureVideoPreviewLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
       break;
     case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
       [captureVideoPreviewLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
       break;
    }

[self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
```

Comment: This indeeds work. HOwever I ended up using captureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

Thank you!

Comment: please note that AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation is marked Deprecated